# Sonar-Runner Scm Activity scm command fails with forbidden in Sonar-Runner but runs fine from command line

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

I'm trying to use version 1.7 of the sonar-scm-activity-plugin-1.7.jar in my sonar-runner execution.  The command (and error) that shows in the log is:

```
Trying to guess scm provider from project layout...
build   30-May-2014 08:39:30    08:39:30.103 INFO  - Found SCM type: svn
build   30-May-2014 08:39:30    08:39:30.103 INFO  - Retrieve SCM blame information with encoding windows-1252...
build   30-May-2014 08:39:30    08:39:30.399 INFO  - Retrieve SCM blame information with encoding windows-1252 done: 296 ms
build   30-May-2014 08:39:30    08:39:30.415 INFO  - Sensor ScmActivitySensor done: 312 ms
build   30-May-2014 08:39:30    08:39:30.415 INFO  - Sensor ScmStatsSensor...
build   30-May-2014 08:39:30    08:39:30.415 INFO  - Collection SCM Change log for the last 1 days
build   30-May-2014 08:39:30    08:39:30.462 INFO  - Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "svn --username ds00 --password ***** --no-auth-cache --non-interactive --trust-server-cert log -v -r "{2014-05-29 13:39:30 +0000}:{2014-05-31 13:39:30 +0000}" https://code.mydomain.org/repos/trunk"
build   30-May-2014 08:39:30    08:39:30.462 INFO  - Working directory: E:\Data\Bamboo\xml-data\build-dir\project-JOB1\modulename
build   30-May-2014 08:39:51    08:39:51.256 WARN  - Fail to retrieve SCM info. Reason: The svn command failed.
build   30-May-2014 08:39:51    svn: E175013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'https://code.mydomain.org/repos/trunk'
build   30-May-2014 08:39:51    svn: E175013: Access to 'https://code.mydomain.org/repos/trunk' forbidden`
```

If I run the same code on the same machine where this build and sonar-runner execution is run I get valid scm output.  The only difference is that I replace the password represented in the log file with the valid password that I cut and paste from the sonar-project.properties file..

I'm running SonarQube 2.4.

I've searched for similar problems but I get returns on my searches relating to maven plugins (not using) and formatting the scm provider url properly.  Since the same URL is returning valid output

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r9754 | j1r    | 2014-05-28 08:38:19 -0500 (Wed, 28 May 2014) | 1 line
Changed paths:
   M /trunk/Build/projects/Util.xml
   M /trunk/Build/properties/Environment.properties
...
```

I believe that the scm provider url is correct.  (note it is listed below for reference)

Any suggestions?  I'm not getting anywhere.  Note usernames, passwords, all paths edited for privacy so if they don't agree ignore it.

```
sonar.scm.enabled=true
sonar.scm.user.secured=ds00
sonar.scm.password.secured=0nL1gj@n!@#5
sonar.scm.url=scm:svn:https://code.mydomain.org/repos/trunk
```

the command in the logs is:

```
"svn --username ds00 --password 0nL1gj@n!@#5 --no-auth-cache --non-interactive --trust-server-cert log -v -r "{2014-05-28 13:43:10 +0000}:{2014-05-31 13:43:10 +0000}" https://code.mydomain.org/repos/trunk"
```

Again, it (the svn command that sonar-runner uses) works from the command line on the same server where the sonar-runner job is failing.  All variables (JAVA_HOME, etc.) are set in the sonar-runner.bat file.

Comment: found a solution ? i'm stuck with this one.

Comment: Stored credentials in subversion config. Job done.